# Java2OP interface with generic parameters

Tags: java, android, kotlin, delphi, generics

I try to build a Delphi bridge file to access an Android library written in Kotlin. The decompiled .jar has the following declarations:

```java
public interface Function<R> {}

public interface Function2<P1, P2, R> extends Function<R> {
    R invoke(P1 var1, P2 var2);
}

public final class Unit {
    // snip
}

public interface Controller {
    void getNearbyStops(@NotNull Function2<? super List<Stop>, ? super Error, Unit> var1);
}
```

The best result I can get with Java2OP is this Delphi declaration:

```delphi
  Jkotlin_FunctionClass = interface(IJavaClass)
    ['{8F273534-5758-45AB-BC0F-2851C32D3350}']
  end;

  [JavaSignature('kotlin/Function')]
  Jkotlin_Function = interface(IJavaInstance)
    ['{8DFE502E-1AD9-4AD1-8940-BE903549AFC9}']
  end;
  TJkotlin_Function = class(TJavaGenericImport<Jkotlin_FunctionClass, Jkotlin_Function>) end;

  JFunction2Class = interface(Jkotlin_FunctionClass)
    ['{630CDE10-8184-4A7C-9F6C-0F084112415D}']
  end;

  [JavaSignature('kotlin/jvm/functions/Function2')]
  JFunction2 = interface(Jkotlin_Function)
    ['{8090FA02-E298-4606-8035-17A4FB3A4456}']
    //function invoke(p1: J; p2: J): JObject; cdecl;
  end;
  TJFunction2 = class(TJavaGenericImport<JFunction2Class, JFunction2>) end;

  JControllerClass = interface(IJavaClass)
    ['{66D15F2C-39DE-40EE-99F3-3A10A45A93D3}']
  end;

  [JavaSignature('net/company/bla/Controller')]
  JController = interface(IJavaInstance)
    ['{20455085-2AD1-43F1-B9CD-455E8FB7EAD9}']
    procedure getNearbyStops(function2: JFunction2); cdecl;
  end;
  TJController = class(TJavaGenericImport<JControllerClass, JController>) end;

  TRegTypes.RegisterType('Android.JNI.MyBridge.Jkotlin_Function', TypeInfo(Android.JNI.MyBridge.Jkotlin_Function));
  TRegTypes.RegisterType('Android.JNI.MyBridge.JFunction2', TypeInfo(Android.JNI.MyBridge.JFunction2));
  TRegTypes.RegisterType('Android.JNI.MyBridge.JController', TypeInfo(Android.JNI.MyBridge.JController));
```

You see that it has generated `Function2`, but without its generic parameters. The `invoke` method is therefore commented.

Is it possible to modify the Delphi code to support the generic parameters?

Thanks for your help!
Dominik

Comment: This is very likely caused by type erasure. The compiler ensures type safety at compile time and then discards the element type information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The generic parameters are only in the Java source code.

The Java compiler ensures type safety at compile time and then discards the element type information. This is called [type erasure](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/erasure.html).

This is standard behaviour, and your Delphi code may only use the Java code using the plain (non-generic) types.

Comment: Thanks, that's it! Simply use JObject as parameters, and cast them to the desired types on the Delphi side :-)